# Track Processed data in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow, jupyter

- every day I get lots of files during a day. I should process them every day.
- the pipeline can triggered accidentally multiple times per day (for example 5 times per day).
- I stored processed data in parquet format in the data lake.
- every new files related to today are located in today source Folder.
- every time when I process these new files I just need to process new files add them to exist parquet file.

when I receive new files how can I track processed data?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: airflow , pyspark